# Patching using Chef & RPM

Tags: chef-infra, yum

I have project which I need to move from our old upgrade infrastructure to a new CI for our bare-metal HW. We need to ensure multiple site deployments. Now, when we patch system / upgrade (we use the same process) . Building new ISO with new RPM's and then PXE boot a node and then copy yum repo locally on the node and then run upgrade.

1. Install base image which has most of the packages . Which is supported.
2. Continuous patching to the system. Not supported

I will need to run `chef` client which   runs `yum-update` or use chef package resource. 
In my previous job our system was ubuntu and we used to publish tarball  in storage and download that and then run apt-get and everything was handled by the recipes.

This time the system is build on RPM . Don't know if I should build central RPM Repo and then run chef to download RPM repo locally and then run yum update ( that is IO intensive and very slow) or 
I need to post anywhere in the cloud like storage object (buckets) download to the node (small size) which I prefer .

Any recommendations ?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question but you don't need to copy a yum repo to the local disk to use it. A remote path will work just fine and only fetch the RPMs that are actually going to be installed when they are needed to be installed.

Comment: There is a yum cookbook that enables you to configure the remote location of your package repository. See: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/yum